# How to use Reflection when reading properties file

Tags: java, logging, reflection, properties-file

I am trying to use a properties file, named logging.properties, to instantiate an `Handler` while using `java.util.logging` libraries. In the logging.properties file i have the line "handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler". So my code is like this:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ErrorLogger.class.getName());  
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\...\\logging.properties"));
String handlerClass = prop.getProperty("handlers");
logger.addHandler((Handler)Class.forName(handlerClass).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance());
```

`FileHandler` has a no-parameters constructor, but what happens if i change the properties file with some other handlers which classes does not have a no-parameters constructors? To me it seems that the reflection becomes useless. So i changed the code like this:

```
HashMap<String, Callable<Handler>> hm = new HashMap<>();
String firstClass = "FileHandler";
Callable<Handler> firstCall = () -> { return new FileHandler("C:\\Users\\sgate\\OneDrive\\Programmazione\\PetriNetsStudio\\log.log", true);
};
hm.put(firstClass, firstCall);
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ErrorLogger.class.getName());
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\...\\logging.properties"));
String handlerClass = prop.getProperty("handlers");
Handler handler = hm.get(handlerClass).call();
logger.addHandler(handler);
```

with the properties file containing the line "handlers=FileHandler". So if the `Handler` change in the properties files i need to add to the `HashMap` a new `String` and a new `Callable`. Is this a good way to read properties from a properties file that can have the "handlers" line changed with other classes with parameters and no-parameters constructors? I do not like my code.

Comment: "I do not like my code." I don't blame you.  That is tough code to maintain in the long run.  When you have a moment, could you give a little background on your problem and what you're trying to solve with your solution?  It might give us a better chance of helping you out.

Comment: I simply have the first five lines of the above code about reading a properties file for logging purpose and I was wondering: if I were to replace the `Handler` type in the properties file with my own `Handler` but which has only one constructor with parameters, the following code would no longer make sense `logger.addHandler((Handler)Class.forName(handlerClass).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance());`. So if i change something in the properties files I have to fix my code. That's not the purpose of using reflection.

Comment: I do not know what to do. Using reflection seems not the correct way if I can have different classes (Handlers in my case) with different constructors to be read from the properties file. But if I do not use reflection I have to directly create the classes after reading the class name from the properties file. And if I can have different classes to be read, I do not find any other way to do it without my hashmap solution. I am stuck.

Comment: logging in java is unfortunately a difficult thing to setup properly.  It looks like you're using Java's Logging framework.  Generally speaking you do not have to programmatically configure your logging at all.  You should just be able to read a configuration file when you start your application up via VM Parameters.  In the case of Java Logging the file is in properties file style, but you don't have to read it yourself as a properties file.  This is common across all the well known Java logging frameworks: SLF4J, Logback, Apache Commons, Log4J2.

Comment: When you have a moment, I would urge you to read [Introduction to Java Logging](https://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-intro) and try setting up your logging based on one of the methods based in that article.

Comment: I read it. But my problem reagards how to correctly read name classes and build these classes. it doesn't necessarily have to be a `Logger`. Lets say I want to create a `JComponent`, in my properties file I will have a line like "jComponentClassName=jComponentClassPath" but "jComponentClassPath" can be every `JComponent`, like a `JDialog` or a `JPanel`. So if want to create a `JDialog` using the constructor with `Frame` and `String` as parameters my code cannot have a line like this `logger.addHandler((Handler)Class.forName(handlerClass).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance());`. [continue]

Comment: [continue] But if i write this code `logger.addHandler((Handler)Class.forName(handlerClass).getDeclaredConstructor(Frame.class, String.class).newInstance(frame, str));` and suddenly i change the line in properties file so that not a `JDialog` but a `JPanel` must be created, the line of code above is no good. I do not know if I made my self clear. I want a correct way to read from properties file, but reflection does not seems the correct way.

Comment: I forgot to edit the code to make sense with JComponents. My code will be like this: `JComponent jc = (JComponent)Class.forName(jComponentClassName).getDeclaredConstructor(Frame.class, String.class).newInstance(frame, str);`

Comment: Your original post was about logging and really didn't indicate that you wanted to build all your objects via properties files.  Basically what you're trying to build is a Dependency Injection Framework (via properties files).  Which, is difficult.  Perhaps you would use one that is already built?  [Spring Dependency Injection](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dependency-injection).  What you're trying to do is terribly difficult.  While your goal is laudably I would urge you to lean on already existing frameworks for that type of coding.

Comment: Specifically I would recommend looking into Spring's Dependency Injection via XML.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Now I undertand a lot. Again, thank you.